# Ink File Picker 403 error when accessing files

Tags: http-status-code-403, filepicker.io

I have several files uploaded to filepicker (>100) and suddenly I've been getting 403 errors when trying to access them.

The files aren't stored via S3, so that might be part of the problem but it I haven't had issues for months.
When trying to access the file I get the following response:

> No longer authorized to read file

I haven't enabled security, and I'm able to access fiels stored in a different filepicker application from months ago (ex: https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/oDm5UsViTYuGCIPD5TGY)

I'm getting the same error when trying to access files from the developer console, I have no idea how this happened.

edit: Apparently this has been happening **for the past month**!

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was? I am starting to get 403s as well. Just started this morning.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've sent several tweets and their support team an email. [This tweet](https://twitter.com/FilePicker/status/388804745759956992) is the only communication I've received back from them. I've entirely given up on their product, it's not worth my time.